# CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED requests.session() get request

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to get the contents of a page where only https urls work and it does not have a valid certificate.

```
import requests
session_requests = requests.session()

result = session_requests.get("some https url")
```

I am getting the following error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)
```

However if i use this:

```
requests.get('https://url.retail.publishedprices.co.il/login', verify=False)
```

It works, but i need to do the same kind of thing with the `requests.session()` since i am logging in.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [SSLLabs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=url.retail.publishedprices.co.il&ignoreMismatch=on) for this site you will find out that there are several things wrong:

- The name in the certificate does not match the name given in the URL. If you try to access this site with a browser you get an error message too.
- The trust chain is incomplete and thus cannot be validated. Some browsers might try to download the missing intermediate certificate but others will simply fail here too.

Instead of trying to working around this broken setup I recommend to contact the ones who setup the site so that these serious issues gets fixed. After the fixes no workarounds in your script are needed.

Also, I don't consider disabling the validation as an acceptable workaround in this situation. This is a public accessible site which asks for sensitive data (at least username and password). And this site is explicitly enforcing https.

Comment: site is https://url.retail.publishedprices.co.il/login and no there is no sensible data. its public records. login with username no password. anyway to solve it with python?

Comment: @AryehArmon: it's obviously asking for a password. And it is enforcing https. And if this data are public anyway then why not just get it from somewhere else instead of dealing with some broken site?

Comment: @AryehArmon: apart from that disabling validation should work with session too in 2.7.x - see https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/2255.